# fread() with commas outside square brackets as separators

Tags: r, data.table, export-to-csv, fread

I'm trying to use `fread()` to get some data from a website. The data is conveniently set up with comma separators, but I get the error:

```
1: In fread("https://website.com/") :
Stopped early on line 56. Expected 5 fields but found 6. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<0,1,1,x[[0], [1]],0>>
```

This is because the entries before line 56 had a blank on column 4, so something like `<<1,1,1,0>>`, whereas line 56 has something including a comma on column 4, so it splits it into two columns. Now, I want that the whole `x[[y], [z]]` to be in one cell, so I want that my data is separated by a comma, but not when commas are inside square brackets.

**Edit:** The real website is private, so it makes no sense to link it here, but it simply contains data in a csv format. Something like:

```
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
1,0,0,,1
0,0,0,,1
1,1,0,,1
1,1,0,,1
............
0,1,1,x[[0], [1]],0
0,1,0,x[[0], [1]],1
1,0,1,,1
0,0,1,x[[1], [0]],0
............
```

The problem arises with the fact that `x[[0], [1]]` is supposed to be all in one cell, but because of the comma delimiter it is split across two cells.

Is there any way to do this with `fread()?` Or with any other function that serves a similar purpose?

Thank you in advance and sorry if the question is somewhat basic, I'm just getting started with R.

Comment: Please share the actual code giving you that error.

Comment: @rmagno, thanks for answering. The only code I have is fread("https://website.com/"), as it does the job if I manage to get over this error. The website is private anyway so I cannot link the real one here, but it's simply a page with data in csv format. Something like this:
field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
1,0,0,,1
0,0,0,,1
1,1,0,,1
1,1,0,,1
............
0,1,1,x[[0], [1]],0

The problem arises with the fact that x[[0], [1]] is supposed to be all in one cell, but because of the comma delimiter it is split across two cells.

Edit: I'll actually put this in the main body.

Comment: Maybe you can share an initial part (containing the lines triggering the error) of the downloadable file.

Comment: I've added an example of rows from the file in the main body of the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading your CSV file directly from that private website of yours with `fread`, you can download the CSV first and then:

1. Read the lines of the CSV (without any special parsing), that will be equivalent to my `csv_lines <- read_lines(my_weird_csv_text)`;
2. Then, split those read lines according to the regex `"(?!\\])(\\,)(?!\\s\\[)"` as opposed to using the single comma `","` (this ensures that commas within those expressions with `"[["` and `"]]"` are not use as split characters);
3. Finally, from the first row of the resulting matrix (`split_lines`) define the column names of a new dataframe/tibble that has been coerced from `split_lines`.

I hope it's clear.

Basically, we had to circumvent straightforward reading functions such as `fread` or other equivalent by reading line by line and then doing split based on a regex that handles your special cases.

```r
library(readr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)

my_weird_csv_text <- 
"field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
1,0,0,,1
0,0,0,,1
1,1,0,,1
1,1,0,,1
0,1,1,x[[0], [1]],0
0,1,0,x[[0], [1]],1
1,0,1,,1
0,0,1,x[[1], [0]],0"

csv_lines <- read_lines(my_weird_csv_text)

split_lines <- stringr::str_split(csv_lines, "(?!\\])(\\,)(?!\\s\\[)", simplify = TRUE)

as_tibble(split_lines[-1, ]) %>%
  `colnames<-`(split_lines[1, ]) -> tbl

tbl
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>   field1 field2 field3 field4      field5
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>       <chr> 
#> 1 1      0      0      ""          1     
#> 2 0      0      0      ""          1     
#> 3 1      1      0      ""          1     
#> 4 1      1      0      ""          1     
#> 5 0      1      1      x[[0], [1]] 0     
#> 6 0      1      0      x[[0], [1]] 1     
#> 7 1      0      1      ""          1     
#> 8 0      0      1      x[[1], [0]] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion:

From the documentation:

```
'fread' is for regular delimited files; i.e., where every row has the same number of
columns.
```

If the number of columns varies or is irregular because of errors in file generation, an alternative like `readLines` would enable you to process the file line by line--perhaps, using regular expressions like `gsub`, etc.